# Corrplot.mixed plot (number and square together)

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, r-corrplot, hmisc

Trying to put together the coefficient values (lower corner) and significance (upper corner)

Try using corrplot.mixed but doing something wrong

```
library(corrplot)
library(Hmisc)
mydata <- read.csv("HiBAPPaperv2_Corre.csv")
mydata.cor = cor(mydata, method = "pearson")
mydatrou= round(mydata.cor, 2)
H1517 <- cor(mydatrou)
#corrplot(H1517, method = "circle")
H1517_2 <- rcorr(as.matrix(mydata))
# Extract the correlation coefficients
H1517_2$r
# Extract p-values
H1517_2$P
## add all p-values
col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000", "red", "#FF7F00", "yellow", "white",
                       "#00ff11", "#007FFF", "blue", "#00007F"))
col2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#67001F", "#B2182B", "#D6604D", "#F4A582",
                       "#FDDBC7", "#FFFFFF", "#D1E5F0", "#92C5DE",
                       "#4393C3", "#2166AC", "#053061"))
col3 <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "blue")) 
col4 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000", "red", "#FF7F00", "yellow", "#7FFF7F",
                       "#00ff11", "#007FFF", "blue", "#00007F"))
whiteblack <- c("white", "black")

## using these color spectra
corrplot.mixed(H1517, upper = "square", p.mat = H1517_2$P, insig =         "label_sig", addrect = 3,col = col4(10), sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05), pch.cex = 1,
           lower = "number", tl.pos = "lt", tl.col = "black", tl.offset=1, tl.srt = 0)
```

> Cannot plot due to: Error in corrplot(corr, type = "upper", method = upper, diag = TRUE, tl.pos = tl.pos,  : 
>     formal argument "col" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice ...

Answer (score 4):

If you want one set of colours for the lower and upper components, you need to set `lower.col` and `upper.col` to the same value.

Using data from `?corrplot.mixed`:

```
 M <- cor(mtcars)
 ord <- corrMatOrder(M, order = "AOE")
 M2 <- M[ord,ord]
```

`corrplot.mixed(M2, col=rainbow(5))` replicates your error.

```
corrplot.mixed(M2,lower.col=rainbow(5), upper.col=rainbow(5))
```

seems to work (although I wouldn't recommend these colours!)